# JavaScript TimeSequence Array approximate access mechanism

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to implement a TimeSequence Array approximate access mechanism in JavaScript.

My project want to record mutable value with time-stamp on every event in an array, in time sequence manner.

Say, if the event occurs on `2014/10/05 12:59:59 001`,

`val[20141005125959001] = 4;`

on `2014/10/05 13:00:05 234`,

`val[20141005130005234] = 7;`

Then, later,
the code is supposed to to access `val` approximately with a function, that is,

`getVal(20141005125959001) = 4;`

`getVal(20141005130005234) = 7;`

and in addition, when the function access `val` array with **unassigned index** such as

`val[20141005125959002]` or `val[201410051300000100]`, the smart function returns

`getVal(20141005125959002) = 4` // since this is prior timing that the value is going to become `7`

To implement such a function, I wonder what would be the smartest way.

An obvious simple method is scan incrementally whole array index started from the required index val, and that would work when the event is so frequent (mill second base), however, once the event is infrequent, the mill-second incremental index scan is not effective.

Probably I need to add index of index, but I would like to hear smart opinion.

Any idea? thanks.

PS

I post my own solution

See below

Comment: Check "binary search"

Comment: Cool. I have just started to consider the idea by myself. That must be the way. thanks.

Comment: The simplest way would be to keep a sorted array of event times and values, then iterate through the array until the time of the event is less than the time requested, and return the older value at that time.

Comment: I mentioned your suggestion in my Q just in case, and that is wrong method. As you see my code, the resolution is a millisecond. Do you want to iterate through Years of 2000-2014 incrementing 1 millisecond? Obviously No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recording logic

```
var compute = function()
{
    var moment = require('moment');

    var utc = moment().utc();

    var YY = utc.year() - 2000 + '';
    var MM = utc.month() + 1 + '';
    var DD = utc.date() + '';
    var HH = utc.hour() + '';
    var mm = utc.minute() + '';
    var ss = utc.second() + '';
    var msc = utc.millisecond() + '';

    log(YY);
    log(MM);
    log(DD);
    log(HH);
    log(mm);
    log(ss);
    log(msc);

    var preObj = this;

    if (preObj[YY] === undefined)
    {
      preObj[YY] = {};
    }

    if (preObj[YY][MM] === undefined)
    {
      preObj[YY][MM] = {};
    }

    if (preObj[YY][MM][DD] === undefined)
    {
      preObj[YY][MM][DD] = {};
    }

    if (preObj[YY][MM][DD][HH] === undefined)
    {
      preObj[YY][MM][DD][HH] = {};
    }

    if (preObj[YY][MM][DD][HH][mm] === undefined)
    {
      preObj[YY][MM][DD][HH][mm] = {};
    }

    if (preObj[YY][MM][DD][HH][mm][ss] === undefined)
    {
      preObj[YY][MM][DD][HH][mm][ss] = {};
    }

    preObj[YY][MM][DD][HH][mm][ss][msc] = preObj.val;
};
```

reading logic

```
var value = function(utc)
{
  log('--value--');

  var Obj = this;

  var YY = utc.year() - 2000;
  var MM = utc.month() + 1;
  var DD = utc.date();
  var HH = utc.hour();
  var mm = utc.minute();
  var ss = utc.second();
  var msc = utc.millisecond();

  log(YY);
  log(MM);
  log(DD);
  log(HH);
  log(mm);
  log(ss);
  log(msc);


  var iYY = YY;
  while (iYY >= 0)
  {
    if (Obj[iYY] === undefined)
    {
      log('YY NOT found');
      iYY--;
      MM = 12;

    }
    else
    {
      log('YY found');

      var iMM = MM;
      while (iMM >= 1)
      {
        if (Obj[iYY][iMM] === undefined)
        {
          log('MM NOT found');
          iMM--;
          DD = 31;

        }
        else
        {
          log('MM found');

          var iDD = DD;
          while (iDD >= 1)
          {
            if (Obj[iYY][iMM][iDD] === undefined)
            {
              log('DD NOT found');
              iDD--;
              HH = 23;

            }
            else
            {
              log('DD found');

              var iHH = HH;
              while (iHH >= 0)
              {
                if (Obj[iYY][iMM][iDD][iHH] === undefined)
                {
                  log('HH NOT found');
                  iHH--;
                  mm = 59;

                }
                else
                {
                  log('HH found');

                  var imm = mm;
                  while (imm >= 0)
                  {
                    if (Obj[iYY][iMM][iDD][iHH][imm] === undefined)
                    {
                      log('mm NOT found');
                      imm--;
                      ss = 59;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                      log('mm found');

                      var iss = ss;
                      while (iss >= 0)
                      {
                        if (Obj[iYY][iMM][iDD][iHH][imm][iss] === undefined)
                        {
                          log('ss NOT found');
                          iss--;
                          msc = 999;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          log('ss found');

                          var imsc = msc;
                          while (imsc >= 0)
                          {

                            log(imsc);
                            if (Obj[iYY][iMM][iDD][iHH][imm][iss][imsc] === undefined)
                            {
                              log('msc NOT found');
                              imsc--;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                              log('msc found');

                              return Obj[iYY][iMM][iDD][iHH][imm][iss][imsc];

                            }
                          }

                          iss--;
                          msc = 999;

                        }
                      }
                      imm--;
                      ss = 59;
                    }
                  }
                  iHH--;
                  mm = 59;
                }
              }
              iDD--;
              HH = 23;
            }
          }
          iMM--;
          DD = 31;

        }
      }
      iYY--;
      MM = 12;
    }
  }

  return null;

};
```